# Pyinstaller not working after trying to stop it from closing after opening

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, pynput

I have made a script with pynput (and a few other librarys) to automatically click on the screen for a website. It works fine when i run it in vscode or with python itself. I turned it into an exe with pyinstaller and it closes right away after opening. I have seen other stackoverflow questions simalar to this one but their awnswers seem to work for them. I have tried putting the following lines at the bottom of my code. input("Press enter to proceed..."), time.sleep(1), input(), and sys.exit(). None of them do anything different.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
import random
import webbrowser
import sys
time.sleep(1)
botrandom = random.uniform(0.05, 0.06)

mouse = Controller()
time.sleep(1)
webbrowser.open('apple.com')  # Just for example


time.sleep(8)
mouse.scroll(0, 5)
time.sleep(botrandom)
#Move to tool button
mouse.position = (1477,522)
mouse.click(Button.left)
time.sleep(botrandom)
#click multishare
mouse.position = (1476,566)
mouse.click(Button.left)
time.sleep(1)
#scroll down
mouse.scroll(0, 0)



#share row
time.sleep(botrandom)
#share 1
mouse.position = (467,588)
mouse.click(Button.left)
time.sleep(botrandom)
#share 2
mouse.position = (735,588)
mouse.click(Button.left)
time.sleep(botrandom)
#share 3
mouse.position = (1000,588)
mouse.click(Button.left)
time.sleep(botrandom)
#share 1
mouse.position = (1265,588)
mouse.click(Button.left)
time.sleep(botrandom)
mouse.scroll(0, -1.2)


input("Press enter to proceed...")
time.sleep(1)
input()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Run the exe from a command prompt to see if you get more error messages.

Comment: Run the code from the CMD to get the error message. It is probably a hidden-import.

Comment: When i run the program it gives no error message. It just runs, closes the program, and starts a new line.

Comment: Could you add some print() message to determine which line the program has run?

Comment: @gfdsweds I have tried printing a message at the start and end of the script. Nothing seems to happen differently.